# ngAnimate is not adding the proper classes

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have successfully installed ngAnimate with bower, 
on the second step I am adding the module in my app module

```
var mcApp = angular.module('mcApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Then on my repeat directive

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemGroup" class="item">
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

On my css

```
.item {
    opacity: 1;
}

.item.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.item.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I change the itemGroup and the list is been rerendered.
But when I trace I see no ng-enter-active class

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemGroup" class="item ng-scope">
```

I have tested the module loading by adding the $animate into a controller, so the module is been loaded but for some reason does not adds the corresponding classes on ng-repeat.

Comment: Change the css to 
.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

also doesn't work, so I guess the ngAnimate is not been initiated, can I check if it's loaded ?

Comment: ngAnimate only adds `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` classes briefly, when items are added or removed from the list. I don't see any methods for adding or removing items. You will need to create those methods, then watch in your browser's inspector to see the classes being added removed as items are added removed from the list

Comment: Angular version is 1.6.2

Comment: No methods need to be created, only some css.

Comment: Classes are not been added.